# Can hashmaps store vectors of vectors?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, hashmap

So for a uni project I have to find the most time efficient algorithm to a problem given. I know I will have to store 2 dimensional vectors (a matrix) somewhere. This could be a list, a hashmap,  the order doesn't matter I just need eficiency in adding new matrixes and in looking them up.

So for instance each element would be a matrix like this:

```
[[0,1]
 [0,0]]
```

And i want to store multiple of these inside some data structure.
I was thinking of using vectors for the matrix itself and a hashmap, if possible, to store the matrixes.

If i used the hashmaps what would i use as keys? Maybe the number of matrixes already inside the hashmap? Would that work and would that be time efficient?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need a key at all?  You can use a hash_set where the key is the value.  Also, if you want performance do not use a 2d vector to represent a matrix.  Create a matrix class and use a 1d vector for the storage of the data.

Comment: If you don't know what the key of a hashmap is, then hashmap is probably not your choice.

Comment: "Would that work and would that be time efficient?" - just try anything and come back when you know that it is too slow. Once you know that it is too slow, pleaase specify your performance requirements. Don't worry about performance too early. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: "Can hashmaps store vectors of vectors?" The answer is yes. "what would i use as keys? " Anything you like. "Maybe the number of matrixes already inside the hashmap?" No. If you add a matrix and remove a matrix, that number may already exist. "Would that work" What exactly?

Comment: If you need to lookup, you must know already what you want to lookup, so that should be the key.